# Django; query objects through jquery ajax

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I'm not familiar with jquery and I'm creating a project using Django. Now I am trying to create a search function. What I want to do is showing up entries that have a specific word the user input without loading the page.

I'm not sure what this page is using but what I want to create is basically like this page.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/search/

But I don't understand how I can adapt ajax into Django yet,  anyone who can give me an example and tips?

Comment: You can try taking a JQuery course on SoloLearn or W3Schools. You need to write AJAX calls in the template and post a request on a URL where your Django view will receive it, send it corresponding data in return.

Comment: First make it work without ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pissall already mentioned taking a course is surely useful. 
However, what you are looking for is this:

Define the jQuery Link in your Base template first. 
Let's assume your search looks like this:

```
<form id="search" method="get" action=""> 
    <input type="text" id="id_q" name="q"/>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Now you need to fetch the data entered in the form. Put this into your JS File that you have already linked in your base template:

```
$("#id_q").change(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "/search/",   //Replace this with your search URL
    type: "get",       // Querying means getting in HTTP terms
    data: $("#search").serialize(),    // This transforms your search form into a JSON dictionary.
    success: function (data){...}, // Do sth here.
    error: function (xHR, textStatus) {...} // Handle server-side errors here.
});
})
```

Note that this is a rudimental AJAX GET request that you can use as a basis for your search. The `data` is sent to Django looks like this: `{'q': 'Whatever you're searching for'}`. 
In your Django View you can take the q from the request:

```
# Imports
from Django.http import JsonResponse

def search_func(request):
    if request.GET.get('q'):
        q = request.GET.get('q')
        model = YourModel.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
        return JsonResponse(data={'results': model})
    else:
        # Handle empty queries
```

The JSON Response returns a serialized dictionary that looks like the dict you have passed to the `data` attribute of JsonResponse. Within the jQuery function defined above you can access the `'results'` with in the `success` key of the AJAX function as follows:

```
$("#id_q").change(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "/search/",   //Replace this with your search URL
    type: "get",       // Querying means getting in HTTP terms
    data: $("#search").serialize(),    // This transforms your search form into a JSON dictionary.
    success: function (data){
        example = data.results // That's where you get your query results.
        // Handle your results
    }, // Do sth here.
    error: function (xHR, textStatus) {...} // Handle server-side errors here.
  });
})
```

Hope that helps you a little bit.